# What could be the reason why the values of hidden input fields are not being updated in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to update the values of hidden input fields using jQuery, but the changes are not being reflected in the DOM.

This code doesn't work:

```
  const checkoutForm = $("#checkout-form");
  const serviceInput = checkoutForm.find(`input[name="service_indexes"][value^="${serviceIndex}:"]`);
  if (serviceInput.length > 0) {
    // Update value of existing hidden input
    serviceInput.val(`${serviceIndex}:${cart[serviceName]}`); //Doesn't work
  } else {
    // Add new hidden input
    console.log('Add');
    checkoutForm.append(`<input type="hidden" name="service_indexes" value="${serviceIndex}:${cart[serviceName]}">`);
  }
```

But if I add a console log before ending of `if`, it works. Does anyone know why?

```
  const checkoutForm = $("#checkout-form");
  const serviceInput = checkoutForm.find(`input[name="service_indexes"][value^="${serviceIndex}:"]`);
  if (serviceInput.length > 0) {
    // Update value of existing hidden input
    serviceInput.val(`${serviceIndex}:${cart[serviceName]}`); //Works
    console.log('Update Works'); //It also print this in console
  } else {
    // Add new hidden input
    checkoutForm.append(`<input type="hidden" name="service_indexes" value="${serviceIndex}:${cart[serviceName]}">`);
  }
```

I need this line to be functional, but if only works if I add a `console.log` right next to it.

```
serviceInput.val(`${serviceIndex}:${cart[serviceName]}`); //Doesn't work
```

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]?

Comment: You mean in the "Elements" into google console you doesn't seen `<input value="newValue"` ? If yes it's normal, try after update `serviceInput.val()` you will see correct value.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. Let me try to see if I run `serviceInput.val()`

Comment: *changes not reflected in the DOM* - no, because you're changing element *properties* not *attributes*.